# Sitecore - Traversing items for Checkbox to set a root node

Tags: sitecore

I'm looking for a webforms solution to the following Sitecore 7 scenario.

I have a structure and at any point the editor can check a box on an item to mark it as a root node. The idea is I could check ABOUT US as a root point and then the left menu would only show that item and its siblings.

Equally I could redefine a new google anayltics ID for that area of the site

can anyone assist with webform method on how I can check the current item for a checked field and if not present traverse up until it finds that checkbox and use a field from that located item?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to iterate through item or its ancestors to find the one with checked field as root item

```
public Item GetRootItem(Item item)
{
    //Check if you reached the top of your content tree, you better replace the ID with your home page item ID, and then return the home page
    if(item.ID == Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse("{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}"))
       return null;

    //Replace CheckboxFieldName with your field name
    if (item["CheckboxFieldName"] != null && item["CheckboxFieldName"] == "1")
    {
        return item;
    }
    else
    {
         return GetRootItem(item.Parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: In terms of your solution how could this be extended to include a concept of inheritance? Example I mark a checkbox ROOT your method checks for this and I retrieve field values on that item. If there was a secondary checkbox called INHERIT SETTINGS - this means it will search for ROOT using your method, select the required fields but then also check for INHERIT SETTINGS and then look to the next ancestor with ROOT checked and get the same fields which I'd concat the values.This method of looking at ancestors would repeat if INHERIT was also on that item. Thanks